# Kernel logging to Cloud Logging for Container Engine nodes?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-logging

My container logs for Container Engine all show up nice and pretty and divided by application in Cloud Logging, but conspicuously absent are kernel messages. How can I log kernel messages from my bare-metal Container Engine node to Cloud Logging?

Answer (score 0):

The fluentd config for the GCP logging agent on GKE is in [google-fluentd.conf](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/fluentd-gcp-image/google-fluentd.conf). It does not currently include `/var/log/kern.log` as a log source.

I've opened [Issue #18387](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18387) to track that as a potential feature.

Until then, you could either add `/var/log/kern.log` to the fluentd config file running inside the fluentd container on each of your nodes, or run a separate GCP logging agent just for kernel logs on each node. Both of these have the downside that they would not survive node failures or cluster scaling, and you'd need to manually update.